# TypeError:list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Ok I have completely changed my code now so that the customers lists are inside another list. Now I am trying to refer to the individual lists for each customer with a for loop. But when I am trying to access individual values in the customer lists I am getting a TypeError: list indicies must be integers or slices, not list. Here is the code:

```
customers = [ ]
customers.append(["Bilbo","Baggins","Dodge Dart", "120876","March 20 2017"])
customers.append(["Samwise"," Gamgee","Ford Tarus","190645","January 10 2017"])
customers.append(["Fredegar","Bolger","Nissan Altima", "80076","April 17 2017"])
customers.append(["Grima"," Wormtounge","Pontiac G6", "134657", "November 24 2016"])
customers.append(["Peregrin"," Took","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 7 2017"])
customers.append(["Meriadoc","Brandybuck","Ford Focus", "143567", "February 19 2017"])



print("At Holden's Oil Change we use our custom built Python program to keep \
track of customer records \
and to display our company logo!!")
time.sleep(7)

print("Select and option from the menu!")

QUIT = '4'

COMMANDS = ('1','2','3','4')

MENU = """1   Current Customers
2   New Customers
3   Company Logo
4   Quit"""

def main():
    while True:
        print(MENU)
        command = realCommand()
        commandChoice(command)
        if command == QUIT:
            print("Program Ended")
            break

def realCommand():
    while True:
        command = input("Select an option: ")
        if not command in COMMANDS:
            print("That is not an option!")
        else:
            return command

def commandChoice(command):
    if command == '1':
        oldCust()
    elif command == '2':
        newCust()
    elif command == '3':
        Turt()

def oldCust():
    print("%6s%12s%20s%24s%22s" % ("First Name", "Last Name", "Car Make & Model", "Mileage Last Service", "Date Last Oil Change"))
    for i in customers:
        print("%8s%18s%22s%24s%32s" % (customers[i][0],customers[i][1],customers[i][2],customers[i][3],customers[i][4]))
```

the function oldCust() is where the error comes up when the for loop runs it is giving the type error. I've tried it several different ways but each ways sends back the same error.
Here is the whole error that gets returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 264, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 49, in main
    commandChoice(command)
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 66, in commandChoice
    oldCust()
  File "C:\Users\hdaug\Documents\Holden's Personal\Spring 2016-2017\CSCI 1121\HoldensOilChange.py", line 79, in oldCust
    print("%8s%18s%22s%24s%32s" % (customers[i][0],customers[i][1],customers[i][2],customers[i][3],customers[i][4]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: `i` is an element of `customers`, not an index.

Comment: The error message is pretty illuminating imo. Before asking a question here, try and understand what Python is telling you and debug it, you'll benefit from it in the long run :-).

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard

Comment: Thanks for that little bit of advice I got it. dumb question, but i have just pondered it for two days. I've only been doing python for about a month now and it always seems to be the little things that get me hung up!